# Как отправить файл в Swagger (OpenAPI) на сервер с Strapi

Tags: swagger, openapi, strapi

Возникла потребность сформировать код на OpenAPI в Swagger для отправки файла в CSM Strapi.

Answer (score 0):

**У меня получилось так**:

```
    post:
      summary: Загрузка файла
      operationId: Upload
      tags:
        - Users
      requestBody:
        description: Загрузка файла
        required: true
        content:
         multipart/form-data:
            schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Upload'
```

**Сама Схема:**

```
   Upload:
      type: object
      required:
        - files
      properties:
        path:
         type: string
        refId:
         type: string
        ref:
         type: string
        field:
         type: string
        files:
         type: string
         format: binary
```